# Google Test not handling exceptions

Tags: c++, unit-testing, exception

I'm using Google Test to perform tests over a class that might throw an exception. The method I'm testing is:

```
void SerialPortManager::OpenPort(PortID portNo) throw(){
try{
ports[portNo]->Open();
}
catch(exception &e){
    throw;
}
}
```

And the test I'm using to test it is:

```
TEST(SerialPortManagerTest,ExceptionCatchedOnFailedOpen) {
PortID portID = COM1;

MockSerialPort* port1 = new MockSerialPort();
EXPECT_CALL(*port1, Open()).Times(Exactly(1)).WillOnce(Throw(SerialPortOpenErrorException()));

MockSerialPort* port2 = new MockSerialPort();
MockSerialPort* port3 = new MockSerialPort();

MockSerialPortFactory portFactory;
EXPECT_CALL(portFactory, CreateSerialPort(_)).Times(3).WillOnce(
        ReturnPointee(&port1)).WillOnce(ReturnPointee(&port2)).WillOnce(
        ReturnPointee(&port3));

SerialPortManager* serialPortManager = new SerialPortManager(
        (SerialPortFactoryInterface*) &portFactory);

EXPECT_ANY_THROW(serialPortManager->OpenPort(portID));

delete serialPortManager;
}
```

I expected the test to be passed but instead I get:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'SerialPortOpenErrorException'
  what():  Error Opening Serial Port
```

¿How can I test that the exception is thrown?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an exception specifier saying that the function won't throw anything:

```
void SerialPortManager::OpenPort(PortID portNo) throw()
                                                ^^^^^^^
```

But then you try throw an exception out of the function. That will result in `terminate` being called.

If the function is supposed to throw, then remove the exception specifier. If it's not, then handle exceptions in some other way than rethrowing them.

Comment: I would remove the exception specifier anyway.